# How to get first entry for every user including entry ID

Tags: sql, hana

I am attempting to write a query.
From the entries table below, I would like returned one row for each user. The row returned includes entries from computer 1 and computer 2. The row returned should have the lowest date. The resultes are ordered by date asc.

Entries:

`| EntryID | UserID  | Date       | Value        | ComputerID |
|---------|---------|------------|--------------|------------|
| 1       | 21      | 01/03/2013 | Login        | 3          |
| 2       | 22      | 01/04/2013 | Login        | 1          |
| 3       | 21      | 01/05/2013 | Edit         | 3          |
| 4       | 20      | 01/06/2013 | Login        | 2          |
| 5       | 20      | 01/07/2013 | Search       | 2          |
| 6       | 22      | 01/08/2013 | Login        | 4          |
| 7       | 21      | 01/09/2013 | Close        | 3          |
| 8       | 21      | 01/11/2013 | Login        | 1          |
| 9       | 20      | 01/12/2013 | Edit         | 2          |
| 10      | 22      | 01/13/2013 | Search       | 1          |`

This is the desired result of the query I am attempting to write:

`|Userid | First Log Date | EntryID | ComputerID |
|-------|----------------|---------|------------|
| 22    | 01/04/2013     | 2       | 1          |
| 20    | 01/06/2013     | 4       | 2          |
| 21    | 01/11/2013     | 8       | 1          |`

EDIT: I have tried the following but I have trouble getting the correct EntryID:

```
SELECT max(userID) as user, 
min(date) as date, 
max(entryID) as entryID, 
max(computerID) as computerID 
From Entry where computerID in ('1', '2') group by userID order by date ASC
```

Comment: Not so basic. This isn't a simple min and group by.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  or just asking us to do it for you?

Comment: I have tried grouping by the userID and odereing by date asc but I had trouble getting the correct entryid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you flagged this as hana.  I'm going to guess you haven't had to work with relational databases much.

Relational databases operate on data sets.  row level or record level processing is inefficient.  So the trick here is to think of two different sets of data.

- 1 set containing earliest entries (subset of set 2) for a user and
  computer
- 2 set containing all the records

You first need to generate a subset of data based listing the earliest entry for user on a computer.  This is where you use your aggregate function (min) on date and group by user and computer.

You then join this back to the base set to limit the list to the earliest access on a computer for each user.

As such:

```
SELECT A.UserID, A.Date as FirstLogDate, A.EntryID, A.ComputerID
FROM entries A
INNER JOIN (SELECT min(Date) mDate, UserID, ComputerID 
            FROM entries 
            GROUP BY userID, computerID) B
 on A.Date = B.mDate
 and A.userID = B.UserID
 and A.computerID=B.ComputerID
WHERE A.ComputerID in (1,2)
```

You could put the where clause on sub query and you may get some gain in efficiency as the system would limit the data before the join.

Comment: Thank you this works well. Only thing i did was make the where clause A.ComputerID. Thank you very much for the explanation above. You are correct I have not had much time with relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by the min date, getting it from a subquery. This subquery is itself filtered by the main query (in this case, by Userid). Like this:

```
select 
    Userid, Date as FirstLogDate, EntryID, ComputerID
from
    Entries as A
where 
    ComputerID in (1, 2)
    and Date =
        (select
            min(date)
        from
            Entries
        where
            Userid = A.Userid)
```